# Multiple User Profiles in django-userena

Tags: python, django

I am trying to make  multiple profile for Userena - each User can only have one Profile type.  Following other discussions, I am using multiple table inhertience, but when I do this, I cannot get data to be saved into the derived models.  Everything ends up being CommonProfile, which should not be possible/permitted.  Example code follows:

in `models.py`:

```
# models.py
# This is an example of how i've attempted to get 
# multiple user profiles working with Userena
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db import models
from userena.models import UserenaLanguageBaseProfile

class CommonProfile(UserenaLanguageBaseProfile):
    """Common fields for 2 user profiles: Spam and Eggs"""
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    common_field = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    @property
    def is_spam(self):
        """Find out if this is a Spam user"""
        try:
            self.spamprofile
            return True
        except SpamProfile.DoesNotExist:
            return False

    def get_real_type(self):
        """return the real model"""
        if self.is_spam:
            return self.spamprofile
        else:
            return self.eggsprofile

class SpamProfile(CommonProfile):
    spam_field = models.CharField(max_length=20)

class EggsField(CommonProfile):
    eggs_field = models.SmallIntegerField()
```

in `forms.py`

```
# forms.py
# This is the form to sign up a Spam Type Person

from django import forms
from userena.forms import SignupFormTos
from . models import CommonProfile, SpamProfile

class SpamSignupForm(SignupFormTos):
    """signup a Spam Person"""
    common_field = forms.CharField(label='what is your quest')
    spam_field = forms.CharField(label='what kind of spam are you')

    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = super(SpamSignupForm,self).clean()
        #do stuf, same idea for clean_<field>
        return cleaned_data

    def save(self):
        """Save the SpamProfile"""
        user = super(SpamSignupForm,self).save()
        common_profile = user.get_profile()
        spam_profile = SpamProfile(commonprofile_ptr=common_profile)
        spam_profile.spam_field = self.cleaned_data['spam_field']
        spam_profile.save()
        return spam_profile
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem this weekend. Try in your save function

```
def save:
  #your other code
   spam_field = self.cleaned_data['spam_field']
   new_spam_user = SpamProfile.objects.create_user(spam_field)

   return new_user
```

Comment: Just a comment, SpamProfile, as a direct inheritor of CommonProfile and UserenaLanguageBaseProfile, doesn't have a objects.create_user, which means you need to add a UserManager derived manager for the profile.  Or am I missing something implicite in your solution?

Comment: yes you need a manager. You can see how userena implements it in their managers.py file